# JLabel text is not displayed

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I added `JLabel` on `JFrame` and displayed frame on YES button click of `JOptionPane`, it displays frame but didn't display label text.

[image]

```
int yes = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you want to reactivate previous 
       schedule(s)","Reactivate Schedule",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
       JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    if(yes == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        setVisible(false);
        disp_wait.setVisible(true);
        for(int i=0 ; i<options.taskList.size(); i++) {
            dataList = Options.getInstance().getTaskList(); 
            Task task=dataList.get(i);
            boolean active = task.getActive();
            if(active) {
                task.setActive(true);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your code is performing some processing during an event handling. In Java this is a problem, the GUI only gets drawn once all the event handling is processed. Besides that, it would be great to see the code for your JFrame, it probably does not add the Label before calling pack()

Comment: `JFrame disp_wait;
        JLabel wait_lbl;
        
                  disp_wait = new JFrame();
                wait_lbl = new JLabel();
                disp_wait.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                disp_wait.setSize(300,300);
                disp_wait.setLocation(200,200);
                wait_lbl.setText("Please wait...");
                disp_wait.add(wait_lbl);
                disp_wait.pack();`